# Is there a word for an individual item within a cache?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a particular word that represents an individual *item* within a cache, particularly from a programming perspective?

Is *item* the best choice in this particular context? Or do you generally need to know the type of objects within a cache (*i.e. [object] cache*) to refer to them any other way? For example:

*Weapon cache* - contains individual weapons.

*Entity cache* - contains individual entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really - you already have two conflicting answers, and I would have said *Entry* myself.

A cache is just a container, and doesn't say much about what you put inside. Would you expect a common term for *things in a bag*?

If you have to refer to the items stored in the cache without describing (or repeating) their type, pick one of *entry*, *value*, *item* or similar, and just stick with it.  It'll be clear enough.

Comment: I agree with all of this (and I also would have said _entry_).

Comment: "...pick one of entry, value, item or similar" may not apply in most cases and therefore cannot "just stick with it". And you probably meant *entity*, not *entry*, which don't fit either.

Comment: Nope, I definitely meant _entry_: from it's common use denoting an individual item in a list or table of data, it seems to generalise well to membership of an arbitrary container.

Answer (score 2):

The individual items in a cache may be called ***elements*** of the cache.

```
return cache->c_ops;
 * Return the first element in the cache  

return nl_list_entry(cache->c_items.next, struct nl_object, ce_list);
 * Return the last element in the cache

return nl_list_entry(cache->c_items.prev, struct nl_object, ce_list);
 * Return the next element in the cache 

return nl_list_entry(obj->ce_list.next, struct nl_object, ce_list);
 * Return the previous element in the cache
```

That may help.

Answer (score 1):

***Information*** or ***item***. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms

Answer (score 1):

They are referred to as ***values*** in the implementations I'm familiar with.